# Find the language recognized by the given deterministic finite state automaton

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, automata

[image]

I got 01* U 1(01)*01* as my answer. I'm not sure if its right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not quite right: the only word that puts the automaton in state $s_0$ is $\epsilon$, the empty word, and the only words that put the automaton in state $s_1$ are those of the form $01^*$. Thus, the desired regular expression is $01^*+\epsilon$ (or $01^*\cup\epsilon$, if you use that version of the notation). Any string that starts with $1$ ends up permanently in $s_2$, where it’s not accepted, and the same is true of any string with more than one $0$.

Comment: Ah my bad. I see, so its empty string or 01*. For some reason when I copied this I had s1 also accepting 0 from s2 which was an error and explains that. So if the beginning state is a final state, an empty string is recognized by the automaton? @Brian M. Scott

Comment: @Ricardo: Yes; in fact, that’s the only way to get it to recognize the empty string.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer very helpful! I'll accept it as soon as the limit is up.

Comment: @Ricardo: You’re welcome!